# Epson MoverioBT-200 not showing local stream for webrtc getUserMedia API

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia, epson, crosswalk

I am testing [SimpleWebRTC on Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/webrtc.html) and it works fine on an Android phone.

When I try it on Epson Moverio BT-200 the local stream doesn't show anything.

Moverio glasses do show the video stream when getUserMedia is accessed through a Firefox webpage though.

There is an [open bug](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-5833) on the Jira of the Crosswalk project but still no clues on how to resolve it.

Any help would be very much appreciated